# Read a csv file using list comprehension

Tags: python, csv, list-comprehension

I read a csv file this way:

```
links = []
with open(join(input_path,'data.csv')) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for record in (reader):
        if record['link']:
            links.append(record['link'])
```

Now I'm trying this

```
with open(join(input_path,'data.csv')) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    a = [record for record in reader if record['link']]
```

But as I'm returning `record` instead of `record['link']` I got a dict, how can I get the same result  as in the first case using list comprehension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're appending `record['link']`, so that's what you should include in the comprehension:

```
links = [record['link'] for record in reader if record['link']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the same expression as in the call to `links.append()`, i.e. `record['link']`:

```
links = [record['link'] for record in reader if record['link']]
```